# como criar um cronômetro em php com botão de iniciar e finalizar?

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados

de preferência em php, mas pode ser em javascript também  e por favor passem os valores do tempo para uma variável em php, pois vai ter uma input para cadastrar o tempo levando para outra página em php para cadastrar no banco de dados.

agradeço desde já.

Comment: Não sei porque negativaram sua pergunta, mas já digo que em PHP não é possível criar um cronômetro (visualmente falando), para isso, o ideal é que seja em javascript. Porém para passar o input para o PHP, requer uma requisição em JSON. Mas para o que você quer, no PHP, procure ler sobre `buffer` ou [event_buffer_timeout_set](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.event-buffer-timeout-set.php)

Comment: OBS: Não entendi 100% o que deseja, achei que ficou confusa sua pergunta, porém coloquei uma resposta abaixo para um exemplo de um cronometro com start/stop em javascript.

Comment: Em PHP não rola, só se fosse usar ajax e ficar puxando info toda hora. O mais recomendado é jQuery ou o próprio JavaScript msm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Em php creio que não é o que você deseja, visto que ele roda no
>   servidor.

Fiz um código simples em Javascript puro.
Exemplo funcionando no Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/5uswvep8/

Porém não sei se você quer um cronometro ou se quer um contador regressivo.

```
function formatatempo(segs) {
min = 0;
hr = 0;
/*
if hr < 10 then hr = "0"&hr
if min < 10 then min = "0"&min
if segs < 10 then segs = "0"&segs
*/
while(segs>=60) {
if (segs >=60) {
segs = segs-60;
min = min+1;
}
}

while(min>=60) {
if (min >=60) {
min = min-60;
hr = hr+1;
}
}

if (hr < 10) {hr = "0"+hr}
if (min < 10) {min = "0"+min}
if (segs < 10) {segs = "0"+segs}
fin = hr+":"+min+":"+segs
return fin;
}
var segundos = 0; //inicio do cronometro
function conta() {
segundos++;
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = formatatempo(segundos);
}

function inicia(){
interval = setInterval("conta();",1000);
}

function para(){
clearInterval(interval);
}

function zera(){
clearInterval(interval);
segundos = 0;
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = formatatempo(segundos);
}

<span id="counter">00:00:00</span><br>
<input type="button" value="Parar" onclick="para();"> <input type="button" value="Iniciar" onclick="inicia();"> <input type="button" value="Zerar" onclick="zera();">
```

Comment: Eu implementaria ao seu código um ajax mandando um sinal para o php dizendo quando começou a contagem. Então na hora que o usuário clicasse em parar, mandaria outro ajax para o php, e salvaria o tempo como a subtração dos dois horários, e compararia com o tempo que foi enviado pelo formulário (aceitando uma diferença de até 2 segundos, levando em consideração o tempo de envio da requisição) . Dessa forma evitaria inconsistência ou tentantiva de burlar o sistema.